# Azure SQL Server Admin Does Not Have Permission To Create Credential

Tags: sql, azure

I am trying to load data from a file into an Azure SQL database table. I have created a stored access policy and shared access storage in Azure using a powershell script. When I try to create a SQL Server credential using a shared access signature in SSMS, using the following query:

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [https://somestoragelocation.blob.core.windows.net/somestorage]

WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'

, SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXSECRETKeYRemovedXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

I get the following error:

Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
User does not have permission to perform this action.

I am logged into the sql database as the admin user. I am using SSMS v18.3.1.

Comment: Did you followed this tutoril: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15?  I test and it works well. Serve admin account shouldn't get this error. Please ensure again if it's an admin account or database admin.

Comment: There are only two users currently on the sql database. I checked the property page on Azure and the user is the admin of the sql database.

Comment: So strange that there's no error on my side. We can not repeat the error.